# Play Framework - Disconnect an user

Tags: scala, playframework

I'm doing a Scala - Play application and I want to disconnect an user when an admin change his right. For exemple, is an user is logged and an admin upgrade his account to the admin type, I want disconnect this user.How can I do that ?

Comment: It depends, how do you determine if a user is logged in ? Do you store the userId in the Session ?

Comment: Y'es I store the userId

Answer (score 0):

If you stored the `userId` in the `Session` you will need to add the rights of the user in the `Session`.

So that when the user connects, you can check his rights from the session to the ones in your database. If they don't match you can redirect the user to the login page.

Comment: Okay but my problem isn't when the user connects, but if he is already connected and I change his right for a less permissive right he can consult the old page from his old role as he didn't disconnected

Comment: When the user queries a page to the server, you are already checking if the user is connected: probably with a `SecuredAction` and checking if a `userId` is defined in the session. You need to add the other check there: if he doesn't have the role you send an error, otherwise you send the page

Answer (score 0):

just to cover all the bases since the answer here depends specifically on how your application determines if a user is logged in:

if user auth is done with a token generated by a secret that is stored on your user model and checked for validity on every request, you can generate a new secret for the user and all existing tokens will become invalid.